# Width of caption larger than width of listing

Tags: listings, captions

Consider the following working minimal example take from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/742069/1219728):

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\textwidth}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I want the background of the listing to be gray, so I added

```
\lstset{                                                                        
     backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},                                        
}
```

to the preamble. This yields the following:

[image]

As you can see the caption is wider than the listing. How can the caption be made as wide as the listing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `\colorbox` inserts a spacing of `\fboxsep` both on its left and on its right, so the right length is `\linewidth-2\fboxsep`, which means that you have to declare

```
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
     backgroundcolor=\color{gray!10},
} 

\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFont{white}{\color{white}}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{listing}{\colorbox{gray}{\parbox{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep\relax}{#1#2#3}}}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=listing,labelfont=white,textfont=white}

% This concludes the preamble

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Some Code]
public void here() {
    goes().the().code()
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]